# Counting according to query

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of N positive elements. Lets suppose we list all N × (N+1) / 2 non-empty continuous subarrays of the array A and then replaced all the subarrays with the maximum element present in the respective subarray. So now we have N × (N+1) / 2 elements where each element is maximum among its subarray.

Now we are having Q queries, where each query is one of 3 types :

1 K : We need to count of numbers strictly greater than K among those N × (N+1) / 2 elements.

2 K : We need to count of numbers strictly less than K among those N × (N+1) / 2 elements.

3 K : We need to count of numbers equal to K among those N × (N+1) / 2 elements.

Now main problem am facing is N can be upto 10^6. So i can't generate all those N × (N+1) / 2  elements. Please help to solve this porblem.

Example : Let N=3 and we have Q=2. Let array A be [1,2,3] then all sub arrays are :

```
[1] -> [1]
[2] -> [2]
[3] -> [3]
[1,2] -> [2]
[2,3] -> [3]
[1,2,3] -> [3]
```

So now we have [1,2,3,2,3,3]. As Q=2 so :

```
Query 1 : 3 3
```

It means we need to tell count of numbers equal to 3. So answer is 3 as there are 3 numbers equal to 3 in the generated array.

```
Query 2 : 1 4
```

It means we need to tell count of numbers greater than 4. So answer is 0 as no one is greater than 4 in generated array.

Now both N and Q can be up to 10^6. So how to solve this problem. Which data structure should be suitable to solve it.

Comment: are there any time complexity constraints?

Comment: @Sumeet Yeah EACH query should be around O(log N) OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT ONLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have a solution in `O(N + Q*log N)` (More about [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)). The trick is to do a *lot* of preparation with your array before even the first query arrives.

1. For each number, figure out where is the first number on left / right of this number that is strictly bigger.

Example: for array: `1, 8, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1` both `3`'s left block would be position of `8`, right block would be the position of `5`.

This can be determined in linear time. This is how: Keep a stack of previous maximums in a stack. If a new maximum appears, remove maximums from the stack until you get to a element bigger than or equal to the current one. Illustration:

[image: Illustration]

In this example, in the stack is: `[15, 13, 11, 10, 7, 3]` (you will of course keep the *indexes*, not the *values*, I will just use value for better readability).

Now we read `8`, `8 >= 3` so we remove `3` from stack and repeat. `8 >= 7`, remove `7`. `8 < 10`, so we stop removing. We set `10` as `8`'s left block, and add `8` to the maximums stack.

Also, whenever you remove from the stack (`3` and `7` in this example), set the right block of removed number to the current number. One problem though: right block would be set to the next number bigger or equal, not strictly bigger. You can fix this with simply checking and relinking right blocks.

2. Compute what number is how many times a maximum of some subsequence.

Since for each number you now know where is the next left / right bigger number, I trust you with finding appropriate math formula for this.

Then, store the results in a hashmap, key would be a value of a number, and value would be how many times is that number a maximum of some subsequence. For example, record `[4->12]` would mean that number `4` is the maximum in `12` subsequences.

Lastly, extract all key-value pairs from the hashmap into an array, and sort that array by the keys. Finally, create a [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) for the values of that sorted array.

3. Handle a request

For request "exactly `k`", just binary search in your array, for `more/less than`k``, binary search for key `k` and then use the prefix array.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudocode for stack part ? I am not getting it complete

Comment: [Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is a pretty standart data structure, I'm sure you will have it pre-implemented in your language's default library.

Comment: @kajacx Thanks a lot . The stack logic is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an adaptation of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31945031/1327235) I wrote earlier. The first part is exactly the same, but the others are specific for this question.

Here's an implemented a O(n log n + q log n) version using a simplified version of a segment tree.

### Creating the segment tree: O(n)

In practice, what it does is to take an array, let's say:

```
A = [5,1,7,2,3,7,3,1]
```

And construct an array-backed tree that looks like this:

[image: segment tree]

In the tree, the first number is the value and the second is the index where it appears in the array. Each node is the maximum of its two children. This tree is backed by an array (pretty much like a heap tree) where the children of the index `i` are in the indexes `i*2+1` and `i*2+2`.

Then, for each element, it becomes easy to find the nearest greater elements (before and after each element).

To find the nearest greater element to the left, we go up in the tree searching for the first parent where the left node has value greater and the index lesser than the argument. The answer must be a child of this parent, then we go down in the tree looking for the rightmost node that satisfies the same condition.

Similarly, to find the nearest greater element to the right, we do the same, but looking for a right node with an index greater than the argument. And when going down, we look for the leftmost node that satisfies the condition.

### Creating the cumulative frequency array: O(n log n)

From this structure, we can compute the frequency array, that tells how many times each element appears as maximum in the subarray list. We just have to count how many lesser elements are on the left and on the right of each element and multiply those values. For the example array (`[1, 2, 3]`), this would be:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

This means that 1 appears only once as maximum, 2 appears twice, etc.

But we need to answer range queries, so it's better to have a cumulative version of this array, that would look like:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 6)]
```

The `(3, 6)` means, for example, that there are 6 subarrays with maxima less than or equal to 3.

### Answering `q` queries: O(q log n)

Then, to answer each query, you just have to make binary searches to find the value you want. For example. If you need to find the exact number of `3`, you may want to do: `query(F, 3) - query(F, 2)`. If you want to find those lesser than 3, you do: `query(F, 2)`. If you want to find those greater than 3: `query(F, float('inf')) - query(F, 3)`.

### Implementation

I've implemented it in Python and it seems to work well.

```py
import sys, random, bisect
from collections import defaultdict
from math import log, ceil

def make_tree(A):
    n = 2**(int(ceil(log(len(A), 2))))
    T = [(None, None)]*(2*n-1)

    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        T[n-1+i] = (x, i)

    for i in reversed(xrange(n-1)):
        T[i] = max(T[i*2+1], T[i*2+2])

    return T

def print_tree(T):
    print 'digraph {'
    for i, x in enumerate(T):
        print '    ' + str(i) + '[label="' + str(x) + '"]'
        if i*2+2 < len(T):
            print '    ' + str(i)+ '->'+ str(i*2+1)
            print '    ' + str(i)+ '->'+ str(i*2+2)

    print '}'

def find_generic(T, i, fallback, check, first, second):
    j = len(T)/2+i
    original = T[j]
    j = (j-1)/2

    #go up in the tree searching for a value that satisfies check
    while j > 0 and not check(T[second(j)], original):
        j = (j-1)/2

    #go down in the tree searching for the left/rightmost node that satisfies check
    while j*2+1<len(T):
        if check(T[first(j)], original):
            j = first(j)
        elif check(T[second(j)], original):
            j = second(j)
        else:
            return fallback

    return j-len(T)/2


def find_left(T, i, fallback):
    return find_generic(T, i, fallback, 
        lambda a, b: a[0]>b[0] and a[1]<b[1],  #value greater, index before
        lambda j: j*2+2,                       #rightmost first
        lambda j: j*2+1                        #leftmost second
    ) 


def find_right(T, i, fallback):
    return find_generic(T, i, fallback,
        lambda a, b: a[0]>=b[0] and a[1]>b[1], #value greater or equal, index after
        lambda j: j*2+1,                       #leftmost first
        lambda j: j*2+2                        #rightmost second
    )       

def make_frequency_array(A):
    T = make_tree(A)

    D = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        left = find_left(T, i, -1)
        right = find_right(T, i, len(A))
        D[x] += (i-left) * (right-i)

    F = sorted(D.items())
    for i in range(1, len(F)):
        F[i] = (F[i][0], F[i-1][1] + F[i][1])

    return F

def query(F, n):
    idx = bisect.bisect(F, (n,))
    if idx>=len(F): return F[-1][1]
    if F[idx][0]!=n: return 0
    return F[idx][1]

F = make_frequency_array([1,2,3])
print query(F, 3)-query(F, 2) #3 3
print query(F, float('inf'))-query(F, 4) #1 4
print query(F, float('inf'))-query(F, 1) #1 1
print query(F, 2) #2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sorted value-to-index map. For example,

```
[34,5,67,10,100] => {5:1, 10:3, 34:0, 67:2, 100:4}
```

Precalculate the queries in two passes over the value-to-index map:

1. Top to bottom - maintain an augmented tree of intervals. Each time an index is added, 
       split the appropriate interval and subtract the relevant segments from the total:

   ```
   indexes    intervals    total sub-arrays with maximum greater than
   4          (0,3)        67 => 15 - (4*5/2)            = 5
   2,4        (0,1)(3,3)   34 => 5 + (4*5/2) - 2*3/2 - 1 = 11 
   0,2,4      (1,1)(3,3)   10 => 11 + 2*3/2 - 1          = 13
   3,0,2,4    (1,1)         5 => 13 + 1                  = 14
   ```
2. Bottom to top - maintain an augmented tree of intervals. Each time an index is added, 
       adjust the appropriate interval and add the relevant segments to the total:

   ```
   indexes    intervals    total sub-arrays with maximum less than
   1          (1,1)         10 => 1*2/2         = 1
   1,3        (1,1)(3,3)    34 => 1 + 1*2/2     = 2 
   0,1,3      (0,1)(3,3)    67 => 2 - 1 + 2*3/2 = 4
   0,1,3,2    (0,3)        100 => 4 - 4 + 4*5/2 = 10
   ```
3. The third query can be pre-calculated along with the second:

   ```
   indexes    intervals    total sub-arrays with maximum exactly
   1          (1,1)         5 =>         1
   1,3        (3,3)        10 =>         1 
   0,1,3      (0,1)        34 =>         2
   0,1,3,2    (0,3)        67 => 3 + 3 = 6
   ```

Insertion and deletion in [augmented trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Augmented_tree) are of `O(log n)` time-complexity. Total precalculation time-complexity is `O(n log n)`. Each query after that ought to be `O(log n)` time-complexity.

Comment: What is complexity for each query ?

Comment: per query its too much, can there be some more better way ?

Comment: @mat7 One could precalculate the information about the relevant segments of the index map in one pass over it. That could reduce query time-complexity to depend only on how many relevant segments there are for it.

Answer (score 0):

You problem can be divided into several steps:

1. For each element of initial array calculate the number of "subarrays" where current element is maximum. This will involve a bit of combinatorics. First you need for each element to know index of previous and next element that is *bigger* than current element. Then calculate the number of subarrays as (i - i<sub>prev</sub>) * (i<sub>next</sub> - i). Finding i<sub>prev</sub> and i<sub>next</sub> requires two traversals of the initial array: in forward and backward order. For i<sub>prev</sub> you need to traverse you array left to right. During the traversal maintain the BST that contains the biggest of the previous elements along with their index. For each element of original array, find the *minimal* element in BST that is *bigger* than current. It's index, stored as value, will be i<sub>prev</sub>. Then remove from BST all elements that are smaller that current. This operation should be O(logN), as you are removing whole subtrees. This step is required, as current element you are about to add will "override" all element that are less than it. Then add current element to BST with it's index as value. At each point of time, BST will store the descending subsequence of previous elements where each element is bigger than all it's predecessors in array (for previous elements {1,2,44,5,2,6,26,6} BST will store {44,26,6}). The backward traversal to find i<sub>next</sub> is similar.
2. After previous step you'll have pairs K→P where K is the value of some element from the initial array and P is the number of subarrays where this element is maxumum. Now you need to group this pairs by K. This means calculating sum of P values of the equal K elements. Be careful about the corner cases when two elements could have share the same subarrays.
3. As [Ritesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665174/ritesh) suggested: Put all grouped K→P into an array, sort it by K and calculate cumulative sum of P for each element in one pass. It this case your queries will be binary searches in this sorted array. Each query will be performed in O(log(N)) time.

Comment: can step 3 be also done by sorting on K and then an array will store cumulative sum of P i.e a[i]=a[i]+a[i-1]. then for each query we can do binary search ?

Comment: in step1: For each element of original array, find the element in BST that is bigger than current. It's index, stored as value, will be iprev. in this case 67 3 34 10 . iprev of 10 will be 67 but it should be 34.

Comment: @Ritesh 1. You are totally right about step3. Using sorted array will be simpler. 2. I intended to say that you need to find element that is "immediate bigger", i.e. minimal element that is bigger.  Thanks for your corrections, I'll update my answer.